# When is the image of the functional calculus of a self-adjoint operator also self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator, either bounded or unbounded, and $f$ a Borel function. Using the functional calculus we may define $f(A)$ as a linear operator. Are there any known conditions on $f$ such that $f(A)$ will also be self-adjoint?

Comment: If $A$ is bounded and $f$ continuous, then $f(A)$ is self-adjoint if and only if $f$ is real valued. The if part follows from the fact that $f(A)^*= \bar{f}(A)$ and the only if part from the spectral mapping theorem $f\big(\sigma(A)\big) = \sigma \big( f(A)\big)$. I am not sure about generalizations if $A$ is not bounded or $f$ not continuous right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is precisely that $f$ is real valued.

If $f$ is real valued then using the Spectral Theorem
$$
f(A)^*=\bigg[\int_{\sigma(A)}f(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)\bigg]^*
=\int_{\sigma(A)}\overline{f(\lambda)}\,dE(\lambda)=\int_{\sigma(A)}f(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)=f(A).
$$
Conversely, if $f$ is not real (up to a nullset) on $\sigma(A)$, let $L=f^{-1}(\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R)$. We have that $E(L)\ne0$. On $L$ necessarily $\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)\ne0$. Since $i[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]\ne0\in\mathbb R$, then at least one of
$$
L_+=\{\lambda:\ i[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]>0\},
\qquad\qquad L_-=\{\lambda:\ i[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]<0\}
$$
is not a nullset. Say it is $L_+$. Then there exists $n$ such that $L_n=\big\{\lambda:\ i[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]>\frac1n\big\}$ is not a nullset.
$$
[f(A)^*-f(A)]\,E(L_n)=\int_{L_n}[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]\,dE(\lambda)
$$
cannot be $0$, because there has to exist  $\xi\in E(L_n)H$ such that $E_\xi(L_n)\ne0$ and hence we have
$$
i\langle[f(A)^*-f(A)]\xi,\xi\rangle
=i\,\int_{L_n}[\overline{f(\lambda)}-f(\lambda)]\,dE_\xi(\lambda)
\geq\frac1n\,E_\xi(L_n).
$$
Thus $f(A)^*\ne f(A)$ and $f(A)$ is not selfadjoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @MartinArgerami I guess  $f(A)^*=\overline{f}(A).$ Moreover if $f\neq g$ up to nullset on $\sigma(A)$ then $f(A)\neq g(A).$ Now can apply that to $g=\overline{f}.$